# To find Coherence between matrix for compressed sensing

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, signal-processing

I am working on Compressed sensing.I have two vectors one is of size 200 X 800,and other is of size 800 x 800.

Is there any way to find the coherence between these two using matlab?(Coherence measures the maximum correlation between any two elements of two different matric)

Comment: You first need to define "coherence"

Comment: Coherence measures the maximum correlation
between any two elements of two different matric

Comment: Never heard of a correlation between two scalars, unless it's a scalar random variable. Please explain or link the formulas you want to implement.

Comment: You must have the dimensions wrong. To find coherence your matrices would have to have the same number of rows.

Comment: @rlbond.. Coloums of the first matrix and rows of the second matrix .both are 800 each

Comment: Generally coherence is defined between the columns of A and the columns of B, as it is a measure of "closeness" of two linear operators.

Anyway just use a `for` loop.